# Relationship between struct s { T0 t0; T1 t1; ... } and std::tuple<T0,T1,...> t

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

In particular if Tj are built-in types or pointers to built-in types does anyone know of a compiler that does not lay out the memory so `offsetof(s, tj) != &get<j>(t) - &get<0>(t)`?

Comment: The way this is worded, I cannot help but think you are going to do something awful, like taking a pointer to one type and treating it as a pointer to some other type.  Please... don't do that.

Comment: What broken thing are you trying to achieve by getting such knowledge?

Comment: Are you aware that the C++11 standard does not *require* implementations to implement `tuple` in that way? I assume that you do, since you're asking about which "compilers" do it. If you want them implemented a certain way across all platforms, then implement it yourself or use `boost::tuple`. Don't rely on the vagaries of standard library implementations which can *change* from version to version.

Comment: The standard doesn't require anything about the inner layout of `tuple` iirc. Furthermore afaik the easiest way to implement `tuple` will store the elements in reverse order. That should answer the question whether what you are doing is a good idea or not.

Comment: Why all the hate?  I think this is a reasonable question.  The answer, it appears, is "no relationship".

Answer (score 4):

The standard does not require implementations to lay out tuples in *any particular way*. There is at least one popular implementation that lays out the members in reverse order and one that lays them in the order given. *Any layout* is allowed. I implemented a [tuple that layouts the members minimizing padding](https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/wheels/src/default/include/wheels/tuple.h++) and that too would be a legal implementation for a standard library.

Comment: Thanks Senor Fernandes. This was exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate the link to your code. 
It is a shame the mods are being so petty.